# Find the nth term of a specific sequence given the rule python

Tags: python, sequence, rules, arithmetic-expressions

Given a sequence U1, U2, U3,...
and the rule is Ui = U(i-1) - 2*U(i-2)
given the natural number n find Un

Here's my approach

```
n = int(input())
u1 = 1
u2 = 1
for i in range(n//2-1):    
    s = u2 - 2*u1
    t = s - 2*u2
    u1 = s
    u2 = t
if n == 3:
    print(-1)
elif n % 2 != 0:
    print(s)
else:
    print(t)
```

example give n = 3 then the output will be -1
this works for small number but as the n get bigger it's not correct
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is a value of n for which your code produces the wrong result? What is the expected output and what do you get? It seems you asked an [almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73884950/839733) before and that was equally vague.

Comment: Well these tasks are on an exercise website that my class uses, and I submit my code and the website just reports error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do two updates per loop, which requires the special cases for printing the result.  That's harder to get all the cases right.  It would be much easier to just do the updates using the formula:

```py
s = u2 - 2*u1
u1 = u2
u2 = s
```

With that body, the loop should go to `n`, and you shouldn't need the various different cases to print the result.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you are making this harder than it needs to be. You don't need all the branching logic. Just keep track of the two variables. You can assign a tuple to swap them out with new values:

```
def un(n):
    u1, u2 = 1, 1
    for i in range(n):       
        u1, u2 = u2, u2 - (2 * u1)
    return u1

for i in range(15):
    print(un(i), end=' ')
```

This will print:

```
1 1 -1 -3 -1 5 7 -3 -17 -11 23 45 -1 -91 -89
```